# Django dataset with select .extra() give very slow mysql query

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, dataset, django-1.5

I have two models:

```
class PromoCodeGroup(models.Model):
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=__("Last updated at"))
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=__("Last created by"))
    bonus = models.IntegerField()
    affilate = models.ForeignKey(Affilate)

class PromoCode(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(verbose_name=__("Promo code"), unique=True, max_length=100)
    promo_code_group = models.ForeignKey(PromoCodeGroup, null=False)
    is_used = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And i want in one query on PromoCodeGroup and want count PromoCodes with two contidions (all, and with is_used=True). So i do this with .extra to create subquery:

```
PromoCodeGroup.objects.annotate(codes_count=Count('promocode')) \
        .extra(select={'used_codes_count': "SELECT COUNT(*) as used_codes\
    FROM `promocodes_promocode` as pc2 \
            WHERE `is_used` = 1\
    AND pc2.promo_code_group_id=`promocodes_promocodegroup`.`id`"})
```

And in theory it should work quite smooth, when I execute query it's slow and fails. When I run code without annotate it's run faster. Propably it's caused by group by at end of query.

My question is how to prevent GROUP BY query, with using count in Django ORM.

Comment: You should run the generated query directly with EXPLAIN in your SQL server. Probably you could use an additionnal index or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that replacing annotate with .extra.